# xcode5; configuration associated with scheme not using bundle identifier set in plist

Tags: xcode5

I want to create a different version of my app, so need a different bundle id. In the past, this was super simple: create a new configuration, create a copy of the info.plist, then create a new scheme and in the appropriate places set the configuration. In settings, for that configuration, change the info.plist it uses, then edit the values in the plist. This has always worked. When I archive (and archive is using the configuration I specified, or it should be), the value I set for bundle id in the plist associated with the configuration is not getting picked up. How do we do that now, short of having to create a new target? Which would pretty much makes configurations and schemes useless.